# How to remove margins between paragraph

Tags: html, css

Hey how do you remove margin between the paragraphs

and is there better ways to style photos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

<p class="auto-style4">
<img alt="" class="auto-style5" height="500" src="i14png.png" style="float: right" width="500" /><strong>Apple</strong></p>
<p class="auto-style3">
iPhone 
14 Pro</p>
<p class="auto-style6" style="width: 718px; height: 107px">A magical new way to 
interact with iPhone. Groundbreaking safety features designed to save lives. An 
innovative 48MP camera for mind-blowing detail. All powered by the ultimate 
smartphone chip.</p>
<p class="auto-style7" margin=" 0 auto "style="width: 720px; height: 102px">
<span>The new Pro 
camera system adds a 2x optical-quality Telephoto to its zoom range, putting 
tons of framing flexibility in your pocket. Up your frame game.</span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Ps: You need to expand the snipet to see the white gaps

It will be really helpfull if you can show me how to remove it.
Thank you

[White gaps between paragraphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRVFq.png)

Comment: Can you share the css code? you p elements have classes like auto-style6, without to know the css for that class it'S hard to help you. Don't write the stylings inline, use css classes for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove `height` from `p` tags

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

<p class="auto-style4">
<img alt="" class="auto-style5" height="500" src="i14png.png" style="float: right" width="500" /><strong>Apple</strong></p>
<p class="auto-style3">
iPhone 
14 Pro</p>
<p class="auto-style6" style="width: 718px;">A magical new way to 
interact with iPhone. Groundbreaking safety features designed to save lives. An 
innovative 48MP camera for mind-blowing detail. All powered by the ultimate 
smartphone chip.</p>
<p class="auto-style7" margin=" 0 auto "style="width: 720px;">
<span>The new Pro 
camera system adds a 2x optical-quality Telephoto to its zoom range, putting 
tons of framing flexibility in your pocket. Up your frame game.</span></p>

</body>
</html>
```